# Replacing apache with nginx in aws elastic beanstalk via ebextensions

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've succesfully configured an AWS elasticbeanstalk application with  apache ,now i want to replace the apache with nginx server.

I'cant find a proper tutorial ,some of them says that login to your associated ec2 instance and install nginx manually,but i don't think its the right way because elastic beanstalk provides (Modify/add programs via `ebextensions` folder and config file)

So i am looking for a solution that uses `.ebextensions` config files.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be what you're looking for: [Changing Apache to Nginx with PHP FPM on Elastic Beanstalk – Amazon Web Services](http://blog.code-mine.com/2015/11/04/changing-apache-to-nginx-with-php-fpm-on-elastic-beanstalk-amazon-web-services/).

**Edit:** Another possibility is to create a [Custom Platform for Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms.html).